# PowerPoint 2010 file saved in 2003 format is too large

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010, microsoft-powerpoint-2003

I working with PowerPoint 2010. When I save my presentation as a 2003 format, my file is too large.

How can I decrease this size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a large number of images or a number of large images (the usual reason for a presentation's file size growing excessively big), you can compress all images (and remove cropped areas) by doing the following:

1. Select one of your images
2. Click the Format tab under Picture Tools at the top
3. Click Compress Pictures (small button in the Adjust group of buttons)
4. Choose your relevant options
5. Save your document

Answer (score 0):

you need to compress the pictures that you use in the powerpoint with any programme